# Get the first occurrence of one of multiple strings within a string

Tags: java, string, indexof

suppose I have a string ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV. I want the index of an inner string: either GHI, JKL, or MNO; whichever one occurs first. Here is what I have:

```
String Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
int leastIndex = Alphabet.indexOf("GHI");
if( Alphabet.indexOf("JKL") < leastIndex ) leastIndex = Alphabet.indexOf("JKL");
if( Alphabet.indexOf("MNO") < leastIndex ) leastIndex = Alphabet.indexOf("MNO");
return leastIndex;
```

My question is if there is any better way to do this, something like:

```
int leastIndex = Alphabet.indexOf("GHI", "JKL", "MNO);
```

Something that is not so excessive, especially with a longer string with more patterns.

Comment: `alphabet.split("(GHI|JKL|MNO)")[0]`

Comment: @TI that doesn't give the index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
int leastIndex = Math.min(Alphabet.indexOf("JKL"), Alphabet.indexOf("GHI")), Alphabet.indexOf("MNO"));
```

Comment: That doesn't work if any of the strings does not occur.

Answer (score 4):

Try with regex.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(GHI|JKL|MNO)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start()); // starting index
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // matched group
}
```